# Post Archive is not showing year and month

Tags: php, mysql

I am a newcomer in php and mysql. I am trying to display posts from my database as month and year with also counting total post in a month. my code is here...

```
<?php 
    $sql="SELECT YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(post_date)) AS EAR,MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(post_date)) AS MONTH, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL from post GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH";
    $result=mysql_query($sql,$bd) or die("Error:".mysql_error());
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        ?>
        <dl>
         <dt><?php echo $row['YEAR']; ?></dt>
         <dd><a href="posts.php?month=<?php echo $row['MONTH']; ?>"><?php echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row['MONTH']."(".$row['TOTAL'].")" ?></a></dd>
        </dl> 
<?php } ?>
```

But i am not getting correct result i can only see brakets and within the braket total number of posts like (7)
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Replace $row['YEAR'] with $row['EAR'] in your code and use mysqli_ prefix for all functions because all functions with mysql_ prefix are deprecated.

Comment: I have used all functions with mysqli_ prefix and when i use $row['EAR'] i got this message "Notice: Undefined index: EAR in C:\xampp\htdocs\webdreamboy.com\include\sidebarright.php on line 84 "

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo in your query, EAR instead of YEAR. The error tells you just that.

```
<?php 
    $sql="SELECT YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(post_date)) AS YEAR,MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(post_date)) AS MONTH, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL from post GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH";
    $result=mysql_query($sql,$bd) or die("Error:".mysql_error());
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        ?>
        <dl>
         <dt><?php echo $row['YEAR']; ?></dt>
         <dd><a href="posts.php?month=<?php echo $row['MONTH']; ?>"><?php echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row['MONTH']."(".$row['TOTAL'].")" ?></a></dd>
        </dl> 
<?php } ?>
```

See the part:

```
YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(post_date)) AS YEAR
```

Also from your website, it seems that a href is not correct. Try this instead:

```
<a href="<?php echo 'posts.php?month='.$row['MONTH']; ?>">
```

Comment: I am sorry! about that, i fixed that and used mysqli_ prefix for all query but still not getting correct answer... can you please take a look at this website http://webdreamboy.com  at the bottom right sidebar there is a section called archive and there i am trying to show year and months counting all posts corresponding months....... i really need  help asap please!!!